# How can I configure Google Cloud Endpoints to ignore specific methods during API generation?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How can I configure Google Cloud Endpoints to ignore specific methods during API generation ?

I want to expose some methods (but not all) of my FooServiceImpl service as a Cloud Endpoints API.
With an @Api annotation on my FooServiceImpl, Google Cloud Endpoints try to expose ALL public methods (and fails if response class is not OK).

How can I have a public method in my service that Cloud Endpoints will not try to expose in the API ?

A solution would be to have two service classes :

- FooServiceImpl, that contains implementation method
- FooServiceApi, that contains only API-exposed methods and each method calls its implementation in FooServiceImpl

But this is a not-ideal and verbose solution, it means we have two classes for each service, with very similar code...

Answer (score 1):

Class methods appear in the API surface if:

- They are annotated with `@ApiMethod`.
- They are `public` and follow a naming convention for a RESTful method name (replace Resource with the name of your JavaBean):

  - `getResource`
  - `insertResource`
  - `updateResource`
  - `listResource`
  - `removeResource`

The off-the-cuff recommendation is to make the methods you don't want in the public API `private` in your class.

Comment: What if you want to use them from other classes, but not expose them via the endpoint? Or in my case, since endpoints can handle arrays or collections of entity types I need this to be ignored. No sense it putting in another class just to avoid the Endpoints analyzer, I think this is for sure a defect, I filed an issue on it: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10372&thanks=10372&ts=1386300958 Thanks!

Comment: I have tested on App Engine SDK 1.8.8 and the naming convention is not required: ALL public methods are exposed. This is a serious defect with Cloud Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you just need to avoid using the [`@ApiMethod`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apimethod_method-scoped_annotations) annotation in those methods you do not want to expose in your API.

In fact I did not try this, but its documentation says:

> *The annotation @ApiMethod is used to indicate that a method is part of
>   an API.*

So it seems to be pretty clear that if you do not use that annotation, the method will not be part of the API...

Comment: No, unfortunately, Google Cloud Endpoints exposes ALL methods in the class, even if the @ApiMethod is not present (and even the ones that are declared on a superclass !)

Comment: @mickael.lenormand, that's interesting and pretty weird, and the documentation is definitely misleading!